# Language model created with SRILM does not sum to 1

Tags: computational-linguistics, n-grams, language-models

I created an n-gram language model on the Penn Treebank using the following command:

```
ngram-count -text $trainfile -order 5 -lm $temp/templm.ptb -gt3min 1 -gt4min 1 -kndiscount -interpolate -unk
```

This code snippet was taken from Mikolov's rnnlm toolkit.
I tried to check if the created ngram LM is valid, and I think it is not (or maybe I don't understand something).
When I open the created ARPA file, I looked, for example, on all bigrams that start with the word "country":

```
-1.445136   country 's  -0.06955435
-0.91566    country </s>
-1.380222   country <unk>   -0.06098625
-2.46688    country N   -0.06098624
...
-1.756313   country with    -0.06098624
-2.699641   country without -0.06098625
-1.975222   country would   -0.1501413
```

and on the unigram

```
-3.751397   country -0.3271779
```

Now, as I understand (and probably I have a mistake somewhere), the number to the left of all bigrams are the log10 conditional probability: [image: \log_{10}(\Pr(\text{word|prev word=country}))].

In addition, the number to the right of the unigram "country" (which is -0.3271779) is log10 of the backoff.
When I sum all the probabilities P(word|prev word=country) (without the backoff) I get:

[image: \sum_{word\in W} \Pr(\text{word|prev word=country})=0.64]

The backoff number is

[image: 10^{-0.3271779}=0.47078444]

When I add this number to the sum I get 1.110339152, which is higher than 1.
What do I miss? Shouldn't it be equal to one?